# How to develop a connection between static web page on AWS S3 to AWS Lambda in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I want to connect my contact us form written in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript which I am hosting using AWS S3 and I wish to trigger a Lambda Function whenever someone presses submit button and store those details to AWS-RDS and I wish to do the whole coding in java

```html
<form>
    <table id="table1"><font size="6s">
        <tr>
            <td><h4 id="fullname"><b>Full Name:</b></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name' required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="ppp"><b>Email-ID</b></td>
            <td><input type='email' name='mail'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Phone Number:  </b></td>
            <td><input type='tel' name='pno' required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Interested in:</b></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='dob' required></td>
        </tr>

    </table> 
    </font>

    <button id="button3" onclick="location.href='index.html'">Back</button>
    <button id="button4" onclick="location.href='index.html'">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: There's an unclosed `h4` tag and unmatched `</font>` in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use API gateway to expose HTTP(S) endpoint and add processing using lambda. Here are good tutorials:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html

But, lambda will provide great throughput due to scalability and poor latency (up to several seconds). If latency is important for you - my recommendation do not use lambda. Use Java application web server (spring boot, etc.)

Comment: Why would lambda take several seconds to store to rds?

Comment: Can you share more details about "lambda poor latency"  ?  It is quiet the opposite in fact, Lambda scales really well and only cold start might suffer from extra overhead.  How much depends on the programming language you are using and the number of dependencies your code is loading at startup.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq don't mismatch throughput (how many concurrent request can be served) and latency (how much it will take to serve single request). Lambda is good in scaling thus can provide high throughput, but due to "cold" state it can take several seconds to serve simple request. In my experience had two project fails due to attempt to use lambda for UI where latency was important.

Comment: I am well aware of the difference between throughput and latency even if I recognize my above comment is confusing. What I meant is that on an app have a steady usage, cold start should not be a problem. Also, have you consider pruning your apps from it dependencies and apply lazy class loading techniques ? Are you running lambda in a VPC ? If you do, would you reconsider the architecture to avoid VPC ? Worst case is it possible to rewrite that specific lambda function using a low start latency runtime such as NodeJs ? Finally : what is the p99.99 acceptable latency ?

Comment: @SébastienStormacq yes, after failure with lambda we move to plain java spring boot web application. The main point from me is that lambda is good for some of the tasks, but for other is not.